# Symfony Dependency Injection: Maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, symfony, testing, dependency-injection

I have project based on Symfony 4. I wanted to start writing functional tests based on `WebTestCase`. I enabled `framework.test: true` in configuration and provided `APP_ENV=test` in phpunit.

There is issue with services container being built for test env. I literally didn't change anything expect `APP_ENV` and `framework.test`.

When I fetch service from test cached container I end up with:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
```

In stack trace I can see that symfony's DI keeps trying to fetch the same service:

```
 ...
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getPanel_Model_EventService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:483
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getDefaultEventRepositoryService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:525
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getDbReachingEventTranslationProviderService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:509
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getCachingEventTranslationProviderService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:541
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getEventContextTakingTranslatorService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:402
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getModelConfiguratorService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:1089
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getPanel_Model_EventService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:483
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getDefaultEventRepositoryService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:525
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getDbReachingEventTranslationProviderService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:509
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getCachingEventTranslationProviderService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:541
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getEventContextTakingTranslatorService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:402
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getModelConfiguratorService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:1089
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getPanel_Model_EventService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:483
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getDefaultEventRepositoryService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:525
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getDbReachingEventTranslationProviderService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:509
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getCachingEventTranslationProviderService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:541
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getEventContextTakingTranslatorService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:402
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getModelConfiguratorService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:1089
 ContainerE6ODQnH\srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer->getPanel_Model_EventService() at /var/www/html/panel/var/cache/test/ContainerE6ODQnH/srcApp_KernelTestDebugContainer.php:483
...
```

It's weird because I don't have circular reference in my definitions. **In `APP_ENV=dev` everything is OK.**

It looks like for some reason `test` container cannot remember references to existing services in `$this->services` property.

Do you know what are building differences of dev and test containers?

When I compare test container php file with dev version. They are indeed different. No reason why...

**UPDATE**

Here is example of generated service that is in the loop of invocations:

**DEV**

```
    protected function getDefaultEventRepositoryService()
    {
        $a = \ClassRegistry::init('Event');

        $this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\DefaultEventRepository'] = $instance = new \Panel\Events\Repository\DefaultEventRepository($a, ($this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\EventMapper'] ?? ($this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\EventMapper'] = new \Panel\Events\Repository\EventMapper())), ($this->privates['timeProvider'] ?? ($this->privates['timeProvider'] = new \Panel\Core\Utils\CurrentTimeProvider())));

        ($this->services['CakeFramework\\ModelConfigurator'] ?? $this->getModelConfiguratorService())->configure($a);

        return $instance;
    }
```

**TEST**

```
    protected function getDefaultEventRepositoryService()
    {
        $a = $this->getPanel_Model_EventService();

        if (isset($this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\DefaultEventRepository'])) {
            return $this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\DefaultEventRepository'];
        }

        return $this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\DefaultEventRepository'] = new \Panel\Events\Repository\DefaultEventRepository($a, ($this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\EventMapper'] ?? ($this->services['Panel\\Events\\Repository\\EventMapper'] = new \Panel\Events\Repository\EventMapper())), ($this->privates['timeProvider'] ?? ($this->privates['timeProvider'] = new \Panel\Core\Utils\CurrentTimeProvider())));
    }
```

As you can see above there is slight difference. Test environment is using service method `getPanel_Model_EventService`. But in development environment it is injected directly `$a = \ClassRegistry::init('Event');`

This is causing circural reference despite service definition is the same. There is no additional `service_test` files. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try to raise `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1024` in your **php.ini** ? Is this for sure a circular reference?

Comment: Yes, I raised this limit. Result is the same. I updated post with example of generated service from loop of circular invocations. As you can see it's slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated this problem. It's caused by Symfony's configurator mechanism and lack of reporting circular dependencies.

I described this problem with code examples in public repo: https://github.com/kamilwylegala/symfony-configurator-circular-dependency

Switching to factory helped to figure out that there indeed is circular dependency. Using factory raises:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service ...
```